# How Do I Loop Through A List Of Objects and Repeat an RDLC Report Page With Each Object?

Tags: .net, reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a report setup with text boxes for the properties of an object to tie in with. What I'm trying to do is loop through each object in the list and repeat this page with the populated data of each object. This is a subreport within a main report. I am not displaying this as a table with columns. Can one of you fine members point me in the right direction?

Comment: convert your object(s) to a dataset then setup a report to taken said dataset and display how you'd like.

Comment: "and repeat this page with the populated data" what do you mean?

Comment: It's ok, I just created a table and added it to the page and added some text in one column, placeholder in another and spaced it accordingly. I didn't originally use a table, I just threw on some textboxes and some placeholders in other textboxes so when the page came up it populated the data with the first record and didn't repeat the next object on the next page. With the table, the data repeated with the next object on the next page. Hope that's clear.